# how can i convert a datetime format to a date after fetching the datetime from database in a BIRT?

Tags: birt

> how can i convert a date-time format to a date after fetching the date-time from database in a BIRT?

Comment: If you've fetched the date-time from a database, surely it will already be a date? Can you clarify this question?

Comment: @Mark Bannister , as it is coming in date-time format, i just want only date part, foe ex.if it is coming in 1900-01-01 00:00:00 format, then i only want 1900-01-01, but In BIRT, i did't get any function which can allow me to extract only date part because i am writing queries in BIRT. Again please any help?

Answer (score 1):

To format a datetime item so that it only shows the date:

- click on the datetime data item in the BIRT layout pane;
- in the Property Editor - Properties pane, select the Format DateTime tab;
- the `Format as` property will be set to Unformatted by default; you can select from a number of predefined formats from a dropdown list, or if none of these match your desired format, you can select `Custom` from the dropdown list then enter your desired format in the `Format code` property (such as `yyyy-MM-dd`, to get a date formatted like 1900-01-01).